# There is an unexplained space between buttons

Tags: java, javafx

I've a problem with an exercise. There is an unexplained space between the first and the second buttons on the scene. I've change the location of the buttons but still the first one has a space from the second one. What cause this and how can I make this space shorter?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVmzC.jpg

```java
    public void start(Stage myStage) {

        GridPane myPane = new GridPane();
        myPane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        myPane.setHgap(10);
        myPane.setVgap(10);

        Button btn1 = new Button("Computer Scinence");
        Button btn2 = new Button("Chemistry");
        Button btn3 = new Button("Arts");

        DrawText txt1 = new DrawText("Computer Scince","Times Roman",FontWeight.BOLD,FontPosture.ITALIC,20,Color.GREEN);
        DrawText txt2 = new DrawText("Chemistry","Times Roman",FontWeight.BOLD,FontPosture.ITALIC,20,Color.BLUE);
        DrawText txt3 = new DrawText("Arts","Times Roman",FontWeight.BOLD,FontPosture.ITALIC,20,Color.YELLOW);

        GridPane.setConstraints(btn1,0,1);
        GridPane.setConstraints(btn2,1,1);
        GridPane.setConstraints(btn3,2,1);
        GridPane.setConstraints(txt1,0,2);
        GridPane.setConstraints(txt2,0,3);
        GridPane.setConstraints(txt3,0,4);

        myPane.getChildren().addAll(btn1,btn2,btn3,txt1,txt2,txt3);

        Scene myScene = new Scene(myPane,350,190);        
        myStage.setScene(myScene);        
        myStage.setTitle("Exercise 3_3");        
        myStage.show();
    }
```

Comment: have a look at the java doc of GridPane, in particular the specification of how it sizes its content

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can often debug `GridPane` layout issues by turning on the grid lines:

```
myPane.setGridLinesVisible(true);
```

After recreating your application (you did not include your `DrawText` class, so I'm just styling Labels instead) and turning on the grid lines reveals the issue:

[image: screenshot 1]

You can see that the *Computer Science* `Label` at `GridPane` location `0, 1` has a greater width than the *Computer Science* `Button`. This causes the `GridPane` to expand the width of the first column to accommodate the `Label`.

You have a couple of options to resolve this, depending on how you want the layout to work.

**1) Set Column Span**:

If you want to keep the *Computer Science* `Button` the same size, but have the first column's width not expand to fit the `Label`, just have that `Label` span 2 columns:

```
GridPane.setColumnSpan(txt1, 2);
```

[image: screenshot 2]

**2) Increase Button Width**:

If you'd like the *Computer Science* `Button` to expand to fill the rest of the column, you can set its `MaxWidth` property to use the maximum value:

```
btn1.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

[image: screenshot 3]